# Screwed Up Apache Config, How to fix?

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-14.04

I am working on adding another domain to my web server when all of the sudden things are all messed up. My uncle's website works fine, but my website goes to my uncle's website. It was working before I started, when I deleted the subdomain because of issues, it remained broke. Based on searches, I found you should run the following commands:

```
root@koldark:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls
050-koldark.com.conf           500-charliesrepair.com.conf         999-default.conf
200-webapi.koldark.net.conf    501-charliesrepair.com-le-ssl.conf  mystaral.koldark.net-le-ssl.conf
210-mystaral.koldark.net.conf  600-ispmon.wills.ws.conf            webapi.koldark.net-le-ssl.conf
220-wiki.koldark.net.conf      900-mikewills.me.conf               wiki.koldark.net-le-ssl.conf
300-webmin-1421554526.conf     901-mikewills.me-le-ssl.conf
root@koldark:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
204.44.86.234:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server koldark.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/050-koldark.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost koldark.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/050-koldark.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost webapi.koldark.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/200-webapi.koldark.net.conf:1)
                 alias webapi.koldark.net
         port 80 namevhost mystaral.koldark.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/210-mystaral.koldark.net.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost wiki.koldark.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/220-wiki.koldark.net.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost darklands.koldark.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/300-webmin-1421554526.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost charliesrepair.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/500-charliesrepair.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.charliesrepair.com
         port 80 namevhost ispmon.wills.ws (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/600-ispmon.wills.ws.conf:1)
204.44.86.234:443      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server charliesrepair.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/501-charliesrepair.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost charliesrepair.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/501-charliesrepair.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.charliesrepair.com
         port 443 namevhost mystaral.koldark.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mystaral.koldark.net-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost webapi.koldark.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webapi.koldark.net-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias webapi.koldark.net
         port 443 namevhost wiki.koldark.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wiki.koldark.net-le-ssl.conf:2)
104.28.27.29:80        mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/900-mikewills.me.conf:1)
[2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:1b1d]:80 mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/900-mikewills.me.conf:1)
104.28.27.29:443       mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/901-mikewills.me-le-ssl.conf:2)
[2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:1b1d]:443 mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/901-mikewills.me-le-ssl.conf:2)
104.28.26.29:80        mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/900-mikewills.me.conf:1)
[2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:1a1d]:80 mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/900-mikewills.me.conf:1)
104.28.26.29:443       mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/901-mikewills.me-le-ssl.conf:2)
[2400:cb00:2048:1::681c:1a1d]:443 mikewills.me (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/901-mikewills.me-le-ssl.conf:2)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
root@koldark:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled#
```

mikewills.me is my domain and it looks different from the rest of the hosts. Is that a config issue? Can you help me understand what's happening here?

Comment: Restore previous configuration from backup?

Comment: About that backup... some moron (namely me) hasn't configured that.

Comment: I think I have it working again. We'll see after I add back my other domain